# Unittest setUpClass not working

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x

I am trying to get started with unittest, but I am having a problem getting `setUpClass()` to work.  Here is my test code...

```
import unittest

class TestRepGen(unittest.TestCase):
    """ Contains methods for training data testing """

    testvar = None

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.testvar = 6

    def test_method(self):
        """ Ensure data is selected """
        self.assertIsNotNone(self.testvar,"self.testvar is None!")

# run tests
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The assert error message is displayed, indicating that `self.testvar == None`, and has not been changed by `setUpClass()`. Is there something wrong with my code?

I get the same result if I run the code from within my IDE (Wing), or directly from the command line. For the record, I am using Python 3.2.1 under Windows7.

Comment: I've tried your code on Python 2.7 under Windows 7. It works fine; the test passes. If you run _exactly_ the script above, does it really not work for you? The docs for Python 3.3 don't indicate any change in the behavior of `setUpClass`.

Comment: The code you pasted works for me in python27 and python 3.2.1 on windows 7.

Comment: Do you have a reason you are using setUpClass? Why not just use `def setUp(self)` ?

Comment: @Bogdan as their names suggest, `setUp()` and `setUpClass()` serve a different purpose. The first is run for every test case while the latter is run only once for the test suite.

Comment: Do we always need to use @classmethod for setUpClass()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok - it's hands-up time to admit that it was my mistake. I was using 3.1.2 when I should have been (and thought I was) using 3.2.1. I have now changed to the correct version, all is well and the test is passing. Many thanks to all who replied (and sorry for wasting your time :-( ).

Answer (score 10):

setUpClass  is new to the unittest framework as of 2.7 and 3.2.  If you want to use it with an older version you will need to use nose as your test runner instead of unittest.

Comment: *zope.testing*'s testrunner does not support `setUpClass()` either.

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to guess you aren't calling this test class directly, but a derived class.

If that's the case, you have to call up to `setUpClass()` manually -- it's not automatically called.

```
class TestB(TestRepGen):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(TestB, cls).setUpClass()
```

Also, accoding to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.html#class-and-module-fixtures) `class-level fixtures are implemented by the test suite`. So, if you're calling `TestRepGen` or `test_method` some weird way you didn't post, `setUpClass` might not get run.

Comment: agf - I was calling the class directly, but eventually it was going to be subclassed, so your comments are useful.  Thanks.

Comment: @Alan - You should post your solution as an answer and accept it.